# Simple Samba File Share

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I'm trying to setup a simple ubuntu (14.04 lts) file server to allow  win xp and osx machines on the network to have read write permissions to the share without having to authenticate with a password.

I have followed the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html and while I can see the server on the network I can't successfully write to it.

Actually on the XP machine I can create a folder and it does create a folder with the default name (New Folder) on the server but then trying to open the folder gives the following error:

```
\\Srv1\share\New Folder is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions

The specified network name is no longer required
```

And trying to rename the folder gives the following error:

```
Cannot rename file: Cannot read from the source file or disk
```

Running testparms gives the following output:

```
    Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
    rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
    WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
    Processing section "[printers]"
    Processing section "[print$]"
    Processing section "[share]"
    Loaded services file OK.
    Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

    Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

    # Global parameters
    [global]
        server string = %h (SRV1)
        server role = standalone server
        security = USER
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


    [printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No


    [print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


    [share]
        comment = test-share
        path = /srv/samba/share
        read only = No
        create mask = 0777
        guest ok = Yes
```

Here's the shared folder:

```
dvsu@srv1:/etc/samba$ ll /srv/samba/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 3 root   root    4096 May  4 14:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 May  4 14:01 ../
drwxrwxrwx 4 nobody nogroup 4096 May  4 14:38 share/
dvsu@srv1:/etc/samba$
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `browseable = yes` to the `[share]` block in smb.conf to allow Windows computers to successfully browse the share. It should fix your issue with clients being able to write but not read. After changing the config file, restart samba services:

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

Comment: I actually have that in the smb.conf file but for some reason it's not showing up when i run testparm. I have tried editing the comment and that shows up but browseable doesn't. I've tried spelling it browseable and browsable but still doesn't seem to show up!?